# database is not getting connected

Tags: php, mysqli

I am not able to connect to my database. Here's my code could you please help me out.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.hostinger.in');
define('DB_NAME', 'u25*****41_hari');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'u25*****41_hari');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'hariharan');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME,    DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect line 9');
}

$DB_SELECT = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$DB_SELECT) {
        die('Could not connect line 15');
}

$valueone = $_POST['Name'];
$valuetwo = $_POST['Username'];
$valuethree = $_POST['Password'];
$valuefour = $_POST['Mobile_Number'];

$sqlone = "INSERT INTO Account (Name) VALUES ('$valueone')";
$sqltwo = "INSERT INTO Account (Username) VALUES ('$valuetwo')";
$sqlthree = "INSERT INTO Account (Password) VALUES ('$valuethree')";
$sqlfour = "INSERT INTO Account (Mobile_Number) VALUES ('$valuefour')";

if (!mysql_query($sqlone) || !mysql_query($sqltwo) || !mysql_query($sqlthree) || !mysql_query($sqlfour) || !mysql_query($sqlfive)) {
     die('Could not connect name line 33');
}


mysql_close();
?>
```

This is the error I get:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/u256114841/public_html/login.php on line 17
>   Could not connect line 15

Comment: The parameters in `mysqli_select_db` are the wrong way round; it's link first, then database name

Comment: Also, your code is using `mysql_query`. That won't work - you need to use `mysqli_query` instead (and pass the database connection as the first parameter)

Comment: I'm really hoping that the OP doesn't come back and say *"it doesn't work"* type of thing, after that "winded" answer of mine. @andrewsi

Comment: @Fred-ii- - well, if it's sometime within the next couple of hours, you can be sure the OP won't have had time to go through all the links you've provided.

Comment: @andrewsi That's for sure. I guess I could have easily have done up just a rewrite like so many do, but then again, I'd of never have *"taught them how to fish"* ;-)

Comment: @Drew Oh lovely. Then there'd be a new one added to "the club" ;)

Comment: @Drew yeah I knew that ;-)

Answer (score 7):

*Foreword: Make sure that all your form element `name` attributes match the `POST` arrays and that your database uses the correct types for the data input and their lengths.*

---

In mysqli, the connection comes first.

you have

```
$DB_SELECT = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
```

which should read as

```
$DB_SELECT = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
```

Read the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

But... you would be better off using all 4 parameters all in one go:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

while getting rid of `$DB_SELECT = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);`

- Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

However, you are mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_` functions.

Those different APIs **do not** intermix.

Consult the following on Stack:

- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

You also did not post your HTML form to go with your POST arrays.

Make sure that your form does use a POST method and that your inputs all hold the same name attribute.

**N.B.:** `$_POST['Name']` with `name="name"` will fail, if that is what your form element is named as and the same for all the other inputs. **Those are case-sensitive.**

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Additionally, your code is prone to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

You don't need to use seperate queries like that.

Just add the columns and values all in one go.

```
$sqlone = "INSERT INTO Account (Name, Username, Password, Mobile_Number) 
            VALUES ('$valueone', '$valuetwo', '$valuethree', '$valuefour')";
```

Using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for all your values.

I.e.:

```
$valueone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Name']);
```

and doing the same for the others.

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

---

Additional references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Y'all might want to point out the `mysql_query` part; and he's using INSERT in a rather - ah - ideosyncratic manner.

Comment: @andrewsi yeah I just spotted that now.

Comment: @andrewsi yeah.... what a crazy method to do an insert. I'll add an additional note.

Comment: I think he wants to add all those items to the same record. Unless he has a very odd database structure, which I admit I'm not going to rule out.

Comment: @andrewsi Their code is funky. I thought those were different tables. My eyes are spinning a bit. I'll make an additional edit. Thanks mate.

Comment: You're probably overdue for a trip to Tim's.

Comment: @andrewsi hahahaha! wayyy overdue.

Comment: Wow, that's become a comprehensive answer. My only regret is that I have but one up-vote to give.

Comment: i get this..

Undefined index: Mobile in /home/u256114841/public_html/login.php on line 26.

Though my form has "Mobile" as the name. Either '0' or some garbage value like this '2147483647' gets inserted.

Comment: @AsrithaMallemala make sure your form's input element matches the one you have for `$_POST['Mobile_Number']` - is not the same as `name="Mobile"` lettercase and everything must match; or change `$_POST['Mobile_Number']` to `$_POST['Mobile']`. Plus, you need to change the column length for it to `varchar` and using a higher number for the length. the 2147483647 number means that you've reached the limit of the column's type being most likely an `int`. Make sure that all your elements match and the columns match the types. I wrote everything down in my answer. Please read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The correct is

```
mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

You are putting

```
mysqli_select_db ( string $dbname , mysqli $link )
```

Fix this and tell me if worked. For more info, see docs: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php